# Twilio Chat Integration with the property listing website

Tags: design-patterns, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

Our Team is trying to figure out a way to integrate the Programmable Chat of Twilio to our website (A RealEstate listing website).

**UseCases:**

- Tenant(User) should be able to send message to the landlord(User) for
  asking the queries. Landlord should accept the chat invite first to start the communication.
- There should be 1:1 private chat communication between different kind of Users.(T-L or L-L or T-T).

**Approaches:**

- For the first usecase we can have 1:1 channel with userFriendly name and add both T as well as L to the channel. In addition to this we can also attach property listing meta info while creating channel.
- For the second usecase, we can still have 1:1 channel with the L-L, T-T or T-L but without property meta associated.

**Questions for the First Approach:**

- Is there any other better approach that my team can consider to decrease the number of channel creations.
- How do we show the invitation dialogue box to the invited user?

**Questions for the Second Approach:**

- How to we show different names on the both user side. For example on Tenant side we will show landlord name and on landlord side we will show Tenant name in case of T-L 1:1 chat.

**Please comment for further information and thank you in advance for helping out in anyway.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

> Is there any other better approach that my team can consider to decrease the number of channel creations.

If you are going to have users talk 1:1 with each other then you need to have a channel per conversation and there's nothing to do to get around that.

I would recommend closing channels once the conversation is over or after a period of inactivity to keep your total down and you could archive the conversation in your own database as part of this. You can always start a new channel if they start talking again.

> How do we show the invitation dialogue box to the invited user?

This entirely depends on your application and I don't know how I'd answer this without a lot more detail on your side. I would recommend just building and trying a few things to learn what will work well within your application.

Twilio Chat does provide for [push notifications to users about new invitations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/push-notification-configuration), which you may want to use.

> How to we show different names on the both user side. For example on Tenant side we will show landlord name and on landlord side we will show Tenant name in case of T-L 1:1 chat.

Each chat participant must set an identity. If that identity is readable, you can use that as the display. Alternatively, you can set an [arbitrary JSON object as the `attributes` property](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/user-resource#user-properties), in which you could set the actual user name. Finally, you could use the identifier to look up the user name from your own API.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! @philnash for your response. I have now clear view. I will comment if I come up with any queries.

Comment: "You can always start a new channel if they start talking again." If I do this then I won't be able to fetch the old messages correct?

Comment: That is correct, that is why I suggested archiving the messages yourself if you need history.

Comment: I have come up with different solution though. I want to confirm with you. When the archiving of channel is done. We remove the members from the channel but we keep the channel. The members and channel information is always stored in our db so when people send message to that channel again the members are joined to that particular channel again. The only additional thing we have is to fetch the archived channels separately through our API.

Comment: Seems reasonable. Just take a look at the limits too and make sure they won’t be a problem for you: https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/chat-limits

Comment: Ran into issue when I tried to invite user(with the identity that is not present in the user resource list) to the channel it throws me an error that identity not found. I guess the behaviour should be the same as adding members (If not present in user resource list then create user first) then added it to the member of the channel right?

Comment: Yes, you can't invite a user that does not exist yet. You need to create your user first, then invite them.